# Egato EyeTV - why does it need a key when I bought the hardware?

Tags: macos, mac

$TITLE says it all. I have lost my key piece of paper - but have the dongle/USB receiver - why does the software require a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they want to sell software updates apart of the hardware you bought.

I've lost my serial for eye tv 2 too. I've sent them a email requesting a new serial including my hardware specifications (serial number, ...) and they send me back a new serial !